# Cin has no operand >>

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

I don't understand why this isn't working. For some reason I'm getting the error:

`error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

I'm doing this in Visual Studio2010 C++ Express if that helps. Not sure why its handing me this error I've done other programs using `cin`...

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv){
    string file;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        file = argv[1];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please Enter Your Filename: ";
        cin >> file;
    }
}
```

Comment: `#include <string>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

include `<string>`

On top of that I suggest you use getline instead as >> will stop at the first word in your input.

Example:

```
std::cin >> file; // User inputs C:\Users\Andrew Finnell\Documents\MyFile.txt
```

The result is "C:\Users\Andrew", quite unexpected considering that the data is not consumed until the newline and, the next std::string read will automatically be consumed and filled with "Finnell\Documnts\MyFile.txt"

```
std::getline(std::cin, file);
```

This will consume all text until the newline.

Comment: What do you mean by ">> doesn't work well with std::string's"?

Comment: @Benjamin : If the user types in a filename containing a space, things won't go as expected with `operator>>`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Clearly.  That's exactly what `operator>>` is specified to do.  Doing what one is specified to do is not what I'd call "not working well".

Comment: @Benjamin : Of course; while Andrew's point is contextually valid, I agree it's not worded well.

Comment: My wording could be better, but it is not obvious or intuitive that std::cin >> file would only consume the first "word" of input, especially considering that std::cin >> file will not be processed until the user creates a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include `<string>`, which is where that function is defined.  Remember that each type defines its own `operator>>` as a static function for manipulation via a stream. an input stream could not possibly be written to account for all types that may be created in the future, so it is extended this way.