# C++ cin and strnicmp not working

Tags: c++, cin

```
void searchFlight(cust flights[] ,int row)
{    
    clrscr();
    cout << "Search for the flight you are looking for.\n";

    string airport;

    cout << "Enter Departing Flight : ";
    cin >> airport;   //error

    for (int r=0;r<row;r++)
    {
        if (strnicmp(airport, flights[r].airport[20], strlen(airport) ==0) //error  
        {
            clrscr();
            cout << flights[r].name[20] <<endl;
            cout << flights[r].airport[20] <<endl;
            cout << flights[r].destination[20] <<endl;
            cout << flights[r].ticket <<endl;
            cout << flights[r].passangers <<endl;
            cout << flights[r].opCost <<endl;
            cout << flights[r].income <<endl;
            cout << flights[r].netProfit <<endl;;
            pressKey();
        }
    }
    pressKey();
}
```

For the cin error:
error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

For the strnicmp error:
error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const char *'

I have searched for solutions to this problem and could not fix it. Apologies if there is a similar post on here which could have solved my problems.

Comment: Are you including "<string>" ?

Comment: You need to use `std::string::length()` to find the length of a std::string. Also check if you have included the headers <iostream>, <string>.

Comment: This was just asked yesterday.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183008/cin-has-no-operand/10183049#10183049

Comment: make sure you have added <iostream> and <string> headers. and also check if you have added" using namespace std;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the cin error: error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Add `#include <string>` to your CPP file.

> For the strnicmp error: error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const char *'

Confirm that you have `#include <cstring>` to your CPP file, and replace your call with:
    `strnicmp(airport.c_str(), flights[r].airport[20], strlen(airport.c_str()) ==0`.

I suspect that `flights[r].airport[20]` is also incorrect, but I can't know because you didn't post a complete program.

If `cust::airport` is declared like `std::string airport;`, then you need `flights[r].airport.c_str()`.

If `cust::airport` is declared like `char airport[20];`, then you need `flights[r].airport`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! #include <string> works. I was under the impression that 'using namespace std' was all I needed.

Comment: I have done what you said, and I get a new error: cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char' to 'const char *'

Comment: See my most recent edit; You need to say `flights[r].airport`, **not** `flights[r].airport[20]`. The first is the name of the array; the other is the 21st char in the array.

Comment: I think that has fixed it. Thanks vey much!

Comment: `strlen(airport.c_str())` is a bit silly when you can just do `airport.size()`

Comment: I know this isn't part of the question... but I attempted to add the second part of the if statement using '&&' - <code>if ( strnicmp(airport.c_str(), flights[r].airport, strlen(airport.c_str() ) ==0 ) && ( strnicmp (destination.c_str(), flights[r].destination, strlen(destination.c_str() ) ==0 ) ))</code>. This compiled but did not show what I wanted it to

Comment: @user1338894 - Think about this line: `cout << flights[r].airport[20] <<endl;` It prints the single character at the 21st location in the array called `flights[r].airport`. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the following :

```
<fstream>
<istream>
<iostream>
<string>
```

I'm pretty sure you forgot the `<string>`

Here's a test code I ran and it worked flawlessly!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)
{
   string foo;
   cin >> foo;
   cout << foo;
}
```